# How to detect if setTimeout is unloaded by browser when browser tab is minimized?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, background-process, throttling

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays):

> Firefox for Android has a minimum timeout of 15 minutes for inactive
> tabs and **may unload them entirely**.

It states that the browser may unload `setTimeout` (as my understanding) without reloading the whole app.
I am going to wrap setTimeout and create my own version which listens to the `visibilitychange` event and detects if the timeout was unloaded and re-activates the timeout.

My first question is: **How to detect if the timeout was unloaded automatically by the browser?**
I don't want my website to look like it hangs forever when returned from a minimized tab.

Secondly, I checked the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) on setInterval. In my understanding, `setInterval` consumes more resources than `setTimeout`. So, it should be unloaded in a similar manner with `setTimeout`, but the MDN does not mention this behavior.

My second question is: **Is there any situation where setInterval is unloaded by the browser?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: "How to detect if the timeout was unloaded automatically by the browser" I don't think browsers want developers to know that otherwise it would defeat the purpose of saving battery usage from background tabs( if developers use that and fire new timers.)

Can you share your usecase as to what you are using setTimeout for ? Chrome has a list of workarounds depending on usecase https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/#workarounds

Comment: When in foreground I run a task with a timeout, for example about 20seconds. After that, I minimize the tab. I want to make sure that the timeout is always fired, otherwise, the promise returned by the task will never be resolved.

Throttling is totally fine, but I am afraid of a unload

Comment: @hariom it would not defeat the purpose if I can know my timeout is canceled *after* the page becomes active

Comment: Maybe you can store the timestamp(Date.now()) before and after visibility toggle and when the tab is visible check the time difference exceeds 20seconds or not. If yes, call the function, mark that it has been called(so that in case setTimeout is still scheduled to be called  the callback isn't called again)

Comment: @appleapple I think it would in the sense that you can use that to schedule a new timer (even when the tab is not in focus ). Not sure though.

Comment: @hariom if it's only called *after the page becomes active*, it's just an easier and more robust way than manually check for it when active status change.

Comment: @appleapple Yeah, in that case it would be useful.

Comment: @hariom thanks for the tip. However, what if the time diff does not exceed 20 sec? I think it would require another timer with the time being the remaining time, and the (new) timer should be canceled when the page is hidden. How do you think?

Comment: If the time difference is less than 20 seconds nothing needs to be done(as your logic requires action when time exceeds 20 seconds). If the user doesn't come back to the tab even after 20 seconds still nothing needs to be done. But when he comes back to the tab, the time difference logic would again ensure that the callback is called.

Comment: @hariom what if the user comes back before 20 seconds elapse, and, he/she stays in the tab for a long time. The timer will never be fired until he/she leaves the tab and go back. IMHO, this is not ideal.

Comment: Yeah agreed. Missed that scenario. Then this approach won't work.
The other workable solution can be to go for animationInterval approach as mentioned here https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/#animation

It doesn't directly use time though, if you have to use time as a criteria for callback you can use timestamp difference.